# Hashing a PHP serialized object VS hashing a string of serialized object

Tags: php, serialization, hash

I have this PHP code. I serialize a class Foo, and I get the output 'O:3:"Foo":2:{s:6:"Fooa";b:1;s:6:"Foob";s:9:"rogthedog";}'. When I hash this serialized output it is not the same as the hash of the string  itself. Shouldn't the serialized output be a string equivalent to 'O:3:"Foo":2:{s:6:"Fooa";b:1;s:6:"Foob";s:9:"rogthedog";}'?

```
<?php
/* Write your PHP code here */
class Foo {
    private $a = TRUE;
    private $b = 'rogthedog';
}


$c = new Foo;
echo(serialize($c));
# This returns 'O:3:"Foo":2:{s:6:"Fooa";b:1;s:6:"Foob";s:9:"rogthedog";}'

echo(hash('sha256', serialize($c)));
# Not the same as!
echo (hash('sha256', 'O:3:"Foo":2:{s:6:"Fooa";b:1;s:6:"Foob";s:9:"rogthedog";}'));
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

theoretically it is correct if you take only the visible characters but php also adds non-writable characters. I have prepared an example for you, starting from your code that shows the gift in which the invisible characters are placed. then I restored the string with those characters and the ash games

```
<?php
class Foo {
    private $a = TRUE;
    private $b = 'rogthedog';
}


$c = new Foo;
echo(serialize($c));

# this shows all the characters
echo("\n\n");
$test = str_split(serialize($c));
foreach ($test as $char) {
 echo $char."->".ord($char)." || ";
}

echo(hash('sha256', serialize($c)));
echo("\n\n");


$test2='O:3:"Foo":2:{s:6:"'.chr(0).'Foo'.chr(0).'a";b:1;s:6:"'.chr(0).'Foo'.chr(0).'b";s:9:"rogthedog";}';

echo (hash('sha256', $test2)); // YES !!!
```

Comment: And he could remove the invisible characters using `str_replace("\0", "", serialize($c))`. This would make the two hashes equals.

Comment: exactly if you remove them before making the hash the problem does not arise